# toggle icon if div is visible

Tags: jquery, icons, toggle

Hi i'm new in jquery and I need advice :-)

I made this function to collapse divs and toggle icons in a grid view. Everything works fine except that the icon of the opened panel does not toggle when I click to open another panel in my grid.
(each panel has the same class in my grid)

the function is as follow :

//first I hide the panels

```
$(".help_content").hide();
```

// then i make the function to display my panel

```
$(".help_target").click(function(e){    
e.preventDefault();
$(this).next('.help_content').slideToggle("slow" );
```

//then i make my icon toggle

```
 $(this).children('.fa-plus,.fa-minus').toggleClass("fa-minus fa-plus");
```

// finally this line is to close the opened panel when i click on one another

```
 $(".help_target").not(this).next(".help_content").slideUp("slow"/*
```

Now i need to find a way to toggle back the icon to minus when the previous opened panel is closing.
I know maybe i do not explain it the right way so the best thing is to give you the url so you can see my problem : [my dev page](http://dev.numero7.ch/guides-bibliques/ancien-testament/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".help_target").not(this).children('.fa').removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply toogle all .fa-minus before the one cliked:

```
$('.fa-minus').toggleClass("fa-minus fa-plus");
$(this).children('.fa-plus,.fa-minus').toggleClass("fa-minus fa-plus");
```